# Symfony2 - Form validation with query builder - value never valid

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have two entities "meeting" and "Slot" with a one2many relation.

I have a form to update a meeting (just to change the time slot), i want to display only free slot so i've made a query_ builder. It works for the creation, but for the update, there is always a validation error (this value is not valid).

This is my code :

controller

```
public function editAction($id)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entity = $em->getRepository('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Meeting')->find($id);

if (!$entity) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Meeting entity.');
}

$editForm = $this->createForm(new UpdateMeetingType($entity->getUserA(),$entity->getUserB()), $entity);

if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
    $editForm->bind($this->getRequest());

//            var_dump($editForm->getData() );

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $entity->setDeleted(0);
        $entity->setPending(1);
        $entity->setValidated(0);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('meeting_front'));
    }
}
return $this->render('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:MeetingFront:edit.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
));
}
```

form builder

```
public function __construct($userA = null, $userB = null)
{
    $this->userA = $userA;
    $this->userB = $userB;

}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
//        die(var_dump($options));
    $users[] = $this->userA;
    $users[] = $this->userB;
    $builder
        ->add('slot', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot',
                'query_builder' => function(SlotRepository $cr) use ($users) {
                    return $cr->findAllFreeSlotByUsers($users);
                }
            )
        );
 }
```

Repository

```
public function findAllFreeSlotByUsers(array $users){


    $subquery = $this->createQueryBuilder('query1');
    $subquery->select('s')
        ->from('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Meeting', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.slot', 's')
        ->leftJoin('m.userA', 'uA')
        ->leftJoin('m.userB', 'uB')
        ->where('m.userA = :userA')
        ->orWhere('m.userA = :userB')
        ->orWhere('m.userB = :userA')
        ->orWhere('m.userB = :userB')
        ->andWhere('m.validated = 1');

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('query');
    $query->select('s2')
        ->from('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot', 's2')
        ->where($query->expr()->notIn('s2.id', $subquery->getDQL()))
        ->setParameters(array('userA' => $users[0]->getId(), 'userB' => $users[1]->getId()));

    return $query;

}
```

Someone can help me ?

EDIT : If made  this it works

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
//        die(var_dump($options));
    $users[] = $this->userA;
    $users[] = $this->userB;
    $builder
        ->add('slot');
 }
```

=========================== EDIT  ====================================

I've try this

```
public function findAllFreeSlotByUsers(array $users){


    $subquery = $this->createQueryBuilder('query1');
    $subquery->select('s')
        ->from('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Meeting', 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.slot', 's')
        ->leftJoin('m.userA', 'uA')
        ->leftJoin('m.userB', 'uB')
        ->where('m.userA = :userA')
        ->orWhere('m.userA = :userB')
        ->orWhere('m.userB = :userA')
        ->orWhere('m.userB = :userB')
        ->andWhere('m.validated = 1');

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('query');
    $query->select('s2')
        ->from('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot', 's2')
        ->where(
            $query->expr()->orx(
                $query->expr()->notIn('s2.id', $subquery->getDQL()),
                $query->expr()->eq('s2.id', $users[2]->getId())
            )

        )
        ->setParameters(array('userA' => $users[0]->getId(), 'userB' => $users[1]->getId()));

    return $query;

}
```

and

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
//        die(var_dump($options));
    $users[] = $this->userA;
    $users[] = $this->userB;
    $users[] = $builder->getData();

    if ($this->userConnected == User::TYPE_RESSOURCE ) {
        $builder
            ->add('slot', 'entity',
                array(
                    'class' => 'NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot',
                    'query_builder' => function(SlotRepository $cr) use ($users) {
                        return $cr->findAllFreeSlotByUsers($users);
                    }
                )
            )
```

And it's always the same error

string 'slot:
    ERROR: Cette valeur n'est pas valide.

Comment: it may be that at update (edit) the existing selected slot is considered as already occupied (by the current meeting you edit).. and is not included in the valid choices.. try merging the query builder results with the existing selected slot.. does this make sense?

Comment: A slot can be used in multiple meeting. It can't be used by the same user

Comment: check my updated answer and output the result.. that may help to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Insert this code and output the result:

`editAction:`

```
var_dump($entity->getSlot()->getId());
$editForm = $this->createForm(new UpdateMeetingType($entity->getUserA(),$entity->getUserB()), $entity);
```

`buildForm:`

```
'query_builder' => function(SlotRepository $cr) use ($users) {
     $query = $cr->findAllFreeSlotByUsers($users);
     $results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
     foreach ($results as $result) {
         var_dump($result->getId());
     }
     die;
}
```

Try this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $data = $builder->getData();
    $users[] = $this->userA;
    $users[] = $this->userB;
    $builder
        ->add('slot', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot',
                'query_builder' => function(SlotRepository $cr) use ($users) {
                    return $cr->findAllFreeSlotByUsers($users, $data->getSlot());
                }
            )
        );
 }
```

`SlotRepository`: `slot_id` is the second parameters you pass from the entity type

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('query');      
$query->select('s2')
->from('NfidBusinessMeetingBundle:Slot', 's2')
->where(
        $query->expr()->orx(
                $query->expr()->notIn('s2.id', $subquery->getDQL()),
                $query->expr()->eq('s2.id', $slot_id)
        )

)
->setParameters(array('userA' => $users[0]->getId(), 'userB' => users[1]->getId()));
```

Of course, you may need to make some tests if the slot is null, etc.

What may be your **issue**:

Let's assume `NEW` meeting. This a the list of free slots:

```
Slot 1,
Slot 2,
Slot 3,
```

You select `Slot 2`. At edit, because it is used this is the list of free slots:

```
Slot 1,
Slot 3
```

Since `Slot 2` is not on the list you get invalid choice.

Comment: If i try this, i've an error. Call to a member function getSlot to a non object ($data). Where i've to get or define data ? What data is suppose to return, Id Slot ?

Comment: add some tests `if ($data !== null)` - if you're at edit.. get the binded entity and make sure you include the assigned slot

Comment: one minute i'll explain exactly what i believe is your issue

Comment: @Schroby59 - check my updated answer. if this is not the case.. try running in controller `$form->getErrorsAsString();` and post the output in your questions